# How to route all IIS requests to my MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating an MVC 3 app that manages business for client companies. When deployed, incoming requests should prominently feature the name of the client company; thus,
`http://hosteddomain.com/Excelsior/Home/Dashboard/3` should retrieve the home page for a user from client Excelsior.

**Question 1**: On the development server this works fine (`localhost:28497/ClientCompany/...`) because my `RouteConstraint` looks up the business name. However, when I deploy this, how do I tell IIS to send all requests to my app? As it is now, IIS will look for an app named "ClientCompany".

**Question 2**: Is there a better way to do this? For example, using URLs of the form `ClientCompany.hosteddomain.com/SomeAppName/[pages...]`. If so, how do I tell IIS to remap the requests to my app AND how do I get the name of the client company from inside the MVC app?

**Meta-Question 1**: Maybe a better question 1 is how do I make my app be the Default Web Site for IIS?

Thanks for insight
Eric

Comment: default websites run on port 80. In IIS - Shutoff the default port 80 website (Default Web Site) and then create a new website pointing to your application running on port 80.

Comment: @SilverNinja Actually, all I had to do was set the "IIS Web Site / application name" to `Default Web Site` on the Package/Publish Web tab of VS2010's Package/Publish settings.

Comment: @SilverNinja Now that I think about it, your solution is the way to make my application be the default web site without having it called "Default Web Site" -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Question #2, you can get access to the raw url from the `HttpContext.Current.Request`. You can find out anything you want from there.

I would setup Host Headers in IIS for a single application, then parse the url and do whatever you need to from there.

**EDIT**

The only domain name that needs to be registered is the TLD (Top Level Domain), so

subdomain.tld.com is just a sub domain that you need to make a DNS entry for and then setup the IIS Host Headers.

Have a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx

Note that Host Headers don't work if you are using SSL if I remember correctly.

Comment: Can you point me to a reference for setting up Host Headers? I'm utterly new to IIS.

Comment: Thanks but I think I'm not going to do it that way. The reason is `ClientBusiness.hosteddomain.com` has to be registered, which in general I cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [Register Routes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) in your `global.asax`. You just define the pattern you want to accept and designate the controller and action parameters.

Comment: Right, but my problem is getting IIS to route the request to my app.