# MVC Controller routing catch all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes

I have this code for routing:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*anything}",
                defaults: new { controller = "WebCache", action = "Get" }
            );
        }
    }
```

It works well for paths like this: `somesite.com/regular/path` but at the moment I try to get an image `somesite.com/imagetest.jpg` for example, it always return 404 not found and not even enter my action in the controller. After some testing I found out that if I insert any kind of extension it yields this behavior. How can I route every HTTP request to one action in one controller? (Including resources).

I'm pretty new to MVC so I'd love some explanation involving the basics if possible.

Answer (score 0):

trying to comment the first IgnoreRoute statement like below:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*anything}",
            defaults: new { controller = "WebCache", action = "Get" }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still same as before, ignoring requests for file with extensions. Althought the files not really in the path specified, I expect it to at least go through the only action in the only controller in the project which their name also specified in the MapRoute.

Comment: why is the url of the default route {*anything} instead of {controller}/{action}, cuz char '*' is wildcard?

Comment: I need to route every HTTP request to one action in one controller and handle the request myself, I previously achieved this successfully using HttpListener in C# .NET without ASP at all. But my requirements demands that ill use ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: have you registered your routes in global.asax? hope help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096937/how-to-route-all-iis-requests-to-my-mvc-app

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RouteConfigTest
{
    public static void LoadRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, catchAll = "" });
    }
}
```